# Connecting to local NodeJS server from website

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, webserver, socket.io

I am having trouble connecting to our local NodeJS server from a remote website that has a page which tries to connect to it using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myipaddress:8101/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

But it just times out. The port is definitely open and can be accessed by online port checkers, there is also a rule in my firewall to allow anything on that port.

The server script is very basic for now:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8101, {
'log level': 2,
'transports': ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling'],
});

var mysql = require('mysql');
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : '127.0.0.1',
user     : 'NodeJS',
password : 'pass',
database : 'db'
});

var connectedClients = 0 ;
var connectedUserNames = {} ;
// listen on new connections
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { // When someone connects...
socket.emit('Welcome!') ;
})
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

---

Tried:

```
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://myip.com:8101');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
console.log(data);
socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});
</script>
```

Which does not work as expected.

Comment: Your description of how the page is connecting to your server got lost.

Comment: @ebohlman What do you mean exactly?

Comment: "...which tries to connect with it using: But it just times out..." It looks like you were trying to describe how it was accessing your server but your description got swallowed.

Comment: You're trying to download a script from that source not execute a script from that source.

Comment: Well he/she needs to download it first, so that's fine. But then he/she has to actually try to connect to the server, and we haven't seen any of the code that does that.

Comment: @ebohlman The error I'm getting is that is can't find the resource in Google Chrome console.

Comment: Let's get this straight: when you include *only* the client-side code you posted, Chrome gives you that exact error? If so, it sounds like you've got some sort of same-origin problem, although socket.io generally takes a lot of care to avoid such things. How about posting (if it's a short, minimal test case) or linking to your *complete* client-side code.

Comment: @ebohlman There is no client side-code. The inclusion of the remote socket.io file should automatically connect me to the server in my building.

Comment: No it won't. Please read the documentation for socket.io. It doesn't work by magic; it gives you a bunch of tools which don't do anything unless you actually try to use them.

Comment: @ebohlman So where would <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> be located on the client? Should that not be referencing socket.io.js on the server?

Comment: Once again, please read the documentation (which, admittedly, doesn't qualify as a masterpiece of writing) for socket.io and actually try out some of the examples given.

Comment: @ebohlman I have done it according to the documentation which I knew would not work. The code is in the edit.